# Loading PreferenceScreen from JAVA

Tags: android, preference

How can we fill PreferenceScreen dynamically (from JAVA).

I have one string array. I want all items to be displayed in second preference screen with checkbox.

Currently I am having

```
CheckBoxPreference
```

tags for each item in string array in preferences.xml.

Any thoughts on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Following code is explained that Implementing the PreferenceActivity Dynamically.Edit in your way.

```
public class DynamicPreference extends PreferenceActivity{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);

        listView.setId(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        layout.addView(listView);

        this.setContentView(layout);

        Preference test1=getPrefereces("key1","Header Preference #1","Summary1",null);

        Preference test2=getPrefereces("key2","Header Preference #2","Summary2",null);


        PreferenceScreen prefScreen=this.getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

        addPreferenceCategory(prefScreen,"Category",test1,test2);

        //addPreferenceCategory(prefScreen,"",test2);
        this.setPreferenceScreen(prefScreen);
            //add Intent to preferences 
        Preference  prefereces=findPreference("key");
        prefereces.setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Nextactivity.class));





    }
    private boolean addPreferenceCategory(PreferenceScreen prefScreen,
            String titleCategory, Preference... preferences) {
        boolean addPreference = false;
        for (Preference preference : preferences) {
            if (preference != null)
                addPreference = true;
        }
        if (addPreference) {

            PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = new PreferenceCategory(this);

            preferenceCategory.setTitle(titleCategory);

            prefScreen.addPreference(preferenceCategory);
            for (Preference preference : preferences) {
                if (preference != null)
                    preferenceCategory.addPreference(preference);
            }
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
    private Preference getPrefereces(String key,String title, String summary,
            Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Preference pref=new Preference(this);
        pref.setTitle(title);
        pref.setSummary(summary);

        if(key!=null)
        {
            pref.setKey(key);
        }
        if(intent!=null)
        {
            pref.setIntent(intent);
        }
        return pref;
    }
}
```